# ngram elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin, analyzer, n-gram

```
curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/testsoundi' -d '{  "settings": {
  "analysis": {
  "analyzer": {
  "my_edge_ngram_analyzer": {
  "tokenizer": "my_edge_ngram_tokenizer"
  }
  },
  "tokenizer": {
  "my_edge_ngram_tokenizer": {
  "type": "edgeNGram", "min_gram" : "2", "max_gram" : "5",
  "token_chars": ["letter", "digit","whitespace"]
  }
  }
  }
  }
  }'


soundarya@soundarya-VirtualBox:~/Downloads/elasticsearch-2.4.0/bin$ curl 'localhost:9200/testsoundi/_analyze?pretty=1&analyzer=my_edge_ngram_analyzer' -d 'wonder'
```

but i am getting the output as wo, won, wond, etc. If I give max_gram as 3, I am getting only till the third letter ('wo','won')

```
I am expecting output like:

won 
ond
nde
der
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good job, you're almost there. First, you need an `nGram` tokenizer, not an `edgeNGram`. The difference is that the latter will only tokenize from the start of the word, while the former will create all possible tokens of the desired length irrespective of the location within the word.

Second if you need tokens of length 3, `min_gram` and `max_gram` need to be 3.

```
curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/testsoundi' -d '{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "my_ngram_analyzer": {
          "tokenizer": "my_ngram_tokenizer"
        }
      },
      "tokenizer": {
        "my_ngram_tokenizer": {
          "type": "nGram",
          "min_gram": "3",
          "max_gram": "3",
          "token_chars": [
            "letter",
            "digit",
            "whitespace"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

'

Comment: Val - I am trying to write an analyzer which splits the tokens on special characters with whitespace, and convert into uppercase. and if I search with lowercase also it should work - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39643533/custom-analyzer-which-breaks-the-tokens-on-special-characters-and-lowercase-uppe - can you help if possible..

Comment: I am not able to accept the answer .. it is saying you should accept after 7 minutes only .. I will definitely do it !

Comment: It would be great if you could help me with that pattern replacement solution as well.. if there is any other way of doing the same also ,let me know. it would be great Val! thanks a ton!

Comment: No worries, I'll have a look !