# elasticsearch mapping analyzer - GET not getting result

Tags: elasticsearch, analyzer, elasticsearch-mapping

I am trying to create an analyzer, which replaces special character with a whitespace and convert it into uppercase. then after, if I want to search with lowercase also it should work.

Mapping Analyzer:

```
soundarya@soundarya-VirtualBox:~/Downloads/elasticsearch-2.4.0/bin$ curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/aida' -d '{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "my_analyzer": {
          "tokenizer": "standard",
          "char_filter": [
            "my_char_filter"
          ],
          "filter": [
            "uppercase"
            ]
        }
      },
      "char_filter": {
        "my_char_filter": {
          "type": "pattern_replace",
          "pattern": "(\\d+)-(?=\\d)",
          "replacement": "$1 "
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
'
{"acknowledged":true}


soundarya@soundarya-VirtualBox:~/Downloads/elasticsearch-2.4.0/bin$ curl -XPOST 'http://localhost:9200/aida/_analyze?pretty' -d '{
"analyzer":"my_analyzer",
"text":"My name is Soun*arya?jwnne&yuuk"
}'
```

It is tokenizing the words properly by replacing the special character with the whitespace. Now if I search a word from the text, it is not retrieving me any result.

```
soundarya@soundarya-VirtualBox:~/Downloads/elasticsearch-2.4.0/bin$ curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/aida/_search' -d '{
"query":{
"match":{
"text":"My"
}
}
}'
```

I am not getting any result out of the above GET query. Getting result like :

```
soundarya@soundarya-VirtualBox:~/Downloads/elasticsearch-2.4.0/bin$ curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/aida/_search' -d '{
"query":{
"match":{
"text":"my"
}
}
}'
{"took":5,"timed_out":false,"_shards":{"total":5,"successful":5,"failed":0},"hits":{"total":0,"max_score":null,"hits":[]}}
```

Can anyone help me with this! Thank you!

Comment: Dumb question, but have you indexed any data after creating your index? The call to `_analyze` will not index anything but simply show you how the text would be analyzed. I think it's the same issue as in your [other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39643533/custom-analyzer-which-breaks-the-tokens-on-special-characters-and-lowercase-uppe)

Comment: yeah, its the same issue. could you please tell me how would I resolve this issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't seem to have indexed any data after creating your index. The call to `_analyze` will not index anything but simply show you how the content you send to ES would be analyzed.

First, you need to create your index by specifying a mapping in which you use the analyzer you've defined:

```
curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/aida' -d '{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "my_analyzer": {
          "tokenizer": "standard",
          "char_filter": [
            "my_char_filter"
          ],
          "filter": [
            "uppercase"
            ]
        }
      },
      "char_filter": {
        "my_char_filter": {
          "type": "pattern_replace",
          "pattern": "(\\d+)-(?=\\d)",
          "replacement": "$1 "
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {                        <--- add a mapping type...
    "doc": {
      "properties": {
        "text": {                      <--- ...with a field...
          "type": "string",
          "analyzer": "my_analyzer"    <--- ...using your analyzer
        }
      }
    }
  }
}'
```

Then you can index a new real document:

```
curl -XPOST 'http://localhost:9200/aida/doc' -d '{
   "text": "My name is Soun*arya?jwnne&yuuk"
}'
```

Finally, you can search:

```
curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/aida/_search' -d '{
  "query":{
    "match":{
      "text":"My"
    }
  }
}'
```

Comment: Awesome. It works now. But have a small question -  it is indexing perfect and search is retrieving me results as well. If I search, for example name in the text field - I still get the result with the special characters only. I am not able to retrieve the result which has been done in the second step (the result after indexing the document)

Comment: The source document will never be modified by ES, the text will be analyzed, tokenized and indexed, but the returned document will always contain the exact same content as the one you indexed.